# Getting StackOverflow error and why?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Why I am getting StackOverflowError at line 11. 
The line that I am getting error: `System.out.println(new JavaInnerClass().callInnerClassMethod(animalQuantity));`

Here is the full code:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
private String animalName;
private int animalQuantity;

public Dog(String animalName, int animalQuantity) {
    animalName(animalName);
    quantity(animalQuantity);
    // JavaInnerClass.tempDog name = new JavaInnerClass.tempDog();
    // System.out.println(name.totalQuantity(animalQuantity));
    System.out.println(new JavaInnerClass().callInnerClassMethod(animalQuantity));
}

@Override
public String animalName(String animalName) {
    this.animalName = animalName;
    return animalName;
}

@Override
public int quantity(int animalQuantity) {
    this.animalQuantity = animalQuantity;
    return animalQuantity;
}
```

}

the JavaInnerClass:

```
public class JavaInnerClass {

Dog[] dog = { new Dog("Husky", 90), new Dog("Boxer", 100) };

tempDog temp = new tempDog();

public static class tempDog {

    public int totalQuantity(int quantity) {
        return quantity + 200; // assuming a statement
    }

}

public int callInnerClassMethod(int quantity) {
    return temp.totalQuantity(quantity);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JavaInnerClass();
}
```

}

Comment: Post the stack trace, or at least the first several lines until it starts repeating. That will show you the exact sequence of recursive calls that are the problem.

Comment: `JavaInnerClass` constructs `Dog` instances on initialization, which in turn constructs a  `JavaInnerClass` instance in its constructor. Hence the stack overflow.

Comment: @chrylis It's entirely possible that the OP doesn't know what a stack trace _is_. It's helpful to have this information, but with obviously new users to Java, you might want to explain what you mean by posting a stack trace.

Comment: @jwir3 The first page of Google results for "stack trace" contains several helpful explanations.

Comment: @chrylis Ah, we're expecting users to _search_ for things now? Sheesh how elitist has SO become? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JavaInnerClass` constructor invokes the `Dog` constructor that invokes the `JavaInnerClass` constructor that invokes the `Dog` constructor ... and so on...

---

Look at the `JavaInnerClass` constructor.

It initializes the array field `dog` :

```
Dog[] dog = { new Dog("Husky", 90), new Dog("Boxer", 100) };
```

But what does the `Dog` constructor ?
It creates an instance of `JavaInnerClass` :

```
public Dog(String animalName, int animalQuantity) {
     ...
    System.out.println(new JavaInnerClass().callInnerClassMethod(animalQuantity));
}
```

And all that goes on until the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating dogs in JavaInnerclass

```
Dog[] dog = { new Dog("Husky", 90), new Dog("Boxer", 100) };
```

They are created everytime a new object is instantiated.

And when you create a new Dog, you create a new JavaInnerClass

```
new JavaInnerClass().callInnerClassMethod(animalQuantity)
```

It's a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that when `Dog` is constructed, the line you mentioned creates a new `JavaInnerClass` object:

```
public Dog(String animalName, int animalQuantity) {
    animalName(animalName);
    quantity(animalQuantity);
    // JavaInnerClass.tempDog name = new JavaInnerClass.tempDog();
    // System.out.println(name.totalQuantity(animalQuantity));
    System.out.println(new JavaInnerClass().callInnerClassMethod(animalQuantity));
}
```

But, then then `JavaInnerClass` constructor creates a new `Dog`:

```
public class JavaInnerClass {
// this program is written to understand inner class..
Dog[] dog = { new Dog("Husky", 90), new Dog("Sheppered", 100) };
...
}
```

Which, in turn, creates a new `JavaInnerClass`, and so on... until the system runs out of stack space.

So, you need to make sure you don't have a cycle of method calls when calling recursive methods. It also seems as though you have a few issues with a class defined inline, so perhaps if you told us what you're trying to do, we might be able to help you out a little more.